# Wordpress template font color change

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress template Simple market and the default text colour is green but I want to change it to black. Even the widgets I install go green. Is there a way to change the whole color rather than changing it in css one by one?

Comment: not recommended but you can use `* { font-color:#000 !important; }` this code should use at the begining.

Comment: sorry you have to use `color` instead of `font-color`

Comment: shall i put it in content?

Comment: Of course no. Put it on `styles.css`. Try to put it before any css rule applied but imports. Thanks

Comment: I changed it! Thank you :-) i used: a:link{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#000000;
 }
 
a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #000000;
 }
 
a:visited{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#000000;
}

Comment: if you want to change the color of all the  text   pass the  css   in your style.css     body{ color:green;}

Answer (score 0):

You can put some CSS in your theme's style.css file to override its green text-color with black text-color, for example:

```
body {
  color: black;
}
```

if the above not work, try something like:

```
body {
  color: black !important;
}
```

This is just a quick patch but not a final solution. When your have better understanding in the theme you mentioned, you can use some tools like Firebug to locate the actual CSS codes and to search and replace them in style.css file which they belong to. That will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Style.css

replace green color(you will find it using colorpix) to black(i.e #000000) using find and replace feature in any stylesheet editor.

Simple enough and no other way.